# Stop Microsoft Office switching account signed into

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-office, microsoft-account

I have two Microsoft Accounts: one for my personal use and another through my University.  I sign into my computer (my personal computer) using my personal account, but am signed in to Microsoft Office (including OneDrive for Business) with my university account, as I am using their license.  I have found recently that when I restart my computer sometimes (i.e. shut it down, leave it and later in the day turn it on) Microsoft Office will have signed in using my personal account (which does not have Office 365 linked to it).  A tell-tale sign of this is that OneDrive for Business will ask me for credentials in a pop-up notification from the taskbar; when I click it nothing happens and OneDrive seems to resolve itself.  When I open OneNote, for example, it has signed in with my personal account.  I have yet to find any related factors in these incidents other than it tends to happen when I turn of my computer at one point in the day and then turn it on later.

Basically what I would like is for this to stop i.e. Office is signed in using my University account *all of the time*!

Another thing I feel I should mention, although is probably of no significance, is that I have added a profile picture to my University account, but that is not reflected in my Office products.  This probably isn't relevant and I am not flagging this as an additional problem, just giving you all the information that may be of use.

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro (signed in with my personal account) and Office 365 Pro Plus (signed in with my University Account), including OneDrive for Business which I use all the time.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I have the same issue and it is incredibly annoying

Comment: @mastazi I had actually forgotten about this issue!  Since I've updated to Windows 10 I haven't encountered the problem so perhaps you might try that

Comment: Thanks, I've found a way so I'll post here a an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience this is what solved the issue on Win 8.1:

- Go to your Office 365 personal account https://stores.office.com/myaccount/home.aspx and click on "Install", then "Deactivate Install" for the computer where you want to switch account.
- In Microsoft Office, before adding a new account and then switch to that, first of all sign out of your current account. To do so (in Word or Excel or PowerPoint) you click on the "Switch account" link and then in the pop-up window click on "sign out", then again click on the "sign out" link that will appear near your account name. You will be warned by a dialogue windows saying that by signing out you might lose your local customisation. This procedure has to be done only once, it signs you out of your account in all your Office apps.
- Finally, you can add the new account and sign in.

Note: you can do the sign out procedure on Outlook too, but the steps are different: Click File -> Office Account -> Sign Out.

Comment: I've accepted this because it better answers the initial problem; my suggestion doesn't actually fix the issue whereas yours does!

Answer (score 1):

Since upgrading to Windows 10, I haven't encountered this issue, so this may provide a fix for the problem!